# How to import markers into Premiere CS5 from file?

Tags: xml, adobe-premiere

We are developing a video annotation tool that can be used for segmenting, annotating and describing videos, quite similar to how ClipNotes worked in Adobe Premiere CS4 but more sophisticated.

Since we're developing the application in Java, we used the ClipNotes XML-format (xfdf) to exchange the segment information with Adobe Premiere. Segment-borders were represented as markers and could thus be imported into Adobe Premiere.

Adobe Premiere CS5 doesn't support ClipNotes anymore, so I was wondering if there is another/better alternative for importing markers from another application into Adobe Premiere using a standard exchange format. I tried to modify the projects-XML description (the prproj-file) but ran into some XML-issues (apparently the order of XML-attributes matters in the project-XML file?!). Is there anyone out there who has an idea how to solve this?